# Css changes does not show in the local host in drupal

Tags: css, drupal-7

Everyone,

I am new in the drupal. I am having a very strange problem. I update the style sheet with gulp and it is successfully updated. 
Then I refresh the site, it shows the changes then I revert the style sheet changes and refresh the site it is not showing the revert changes. but still loading the old sheet in which I made changes. 
Then I dont knnow after some time what happens and it start showing the new sheet. There is some issue with the css sheet loading.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe is cache... server side or your browser

Comment: Yes, Exactly I got the problem it is the server side cache. Is there any method in the drupal through which we delete the cache on each load?

Comment: Check your drupal cache setting, config > performance

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the browser is caching the old CSS. Most browsers will let you reload the page while ignoring any cached info by the keyboard shortcut: **Ctrl+Shift+r**. This would cause it to bypass the cache and load the latest version of your CSS.

Comment: That only does a refresh, doesn't it?

Comment: deleting cache and refreshing page